# Reversing an infix boolean result kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have an infix function, let's say it's this one:

```
class test{
     infix fun equalsTen(value:Int):Boolean = value.equals(10)
}
```

Obviously this isn't the real function, just an example.
Additionally Lets say that I have this function:

```
fun doSomething(value: Int){
    val testClazz = test()
    if(testClazz equalsTen value){//line 3
        //do something
    }
}
```

How can I reverse the condition in line 3?
Right now it's basically:

`if(testClazz.equalsTen(value)){...}`

How can I change it to be:

`if(!testClazz.equalsTen(value)){...}`

While keeping the infix expression?

Comment: There's a request to make you able to call it like `testClazz !equalsTen value` here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5351

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it wrapping it with brackets and using the `not` operator outside them:

```
if (!(testClazz equalsTen value)) { /* ... */ }
```

If you want to make the `infix` function more clear, you can create another `infix` function to reverse it:

```
infix fun notEqualsTen(value:Int) = !equalsTen(value)
```

And use it in this way:

```
if (testClazz notEqualsTen value) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no syntactic sugar for that, you have to do it like this:

```
if(!(testClazz equalsTen value))
```